# Block IP Address range on IIS 7.5

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7.5, ip-address, ip-blocking

I have a Windows 2008R2 Server running IIS 7.5. It is getting bombarded with attempted hacks from similar IPs.

How would I block the IP range with something like 51.255.65.*?

Below is the UI presented to me when adding a Deny restriction

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the range in proper subnet format.  You may wish to take a look at our [canonical question on IPv4 subnetting](https://serverfault.com/q/49765/339727), if you're not exactly sure what that means.

For your example, you'd use `51.255.65.0` in the "IP address range" field, and the subnet mask of `255.255.255.0`. in the "Mask or Prefix" field.

If you're going to be making a habit of this (and also just in general), you may wish to find a [nice subnet calculator](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/) or [subnet mask cheat sheet](https://www.aelius.com/njh/subnet_sheet.html) you like, and add them to your bookmarks.

Comment: Thank you! So to clarify to block 51.255.*.* I would use 51.255.0.0 with a Mask or Prefix of 255.255.0.0

Comment: @PaulHale Yes, that looks correct.